# trouble in npm start due to ELIFECYCLE

Tags: reactjs, npm, window

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
in the react app cant start the project using npm start, I deleted the node_module and npm install but no luck. Deleted the package-lock.json and install npm also doesn't work. Is there any other method to solve this issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to install your app somewhere else on your device via this code :

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

then start your app:

```
npm start
```

**note**: in the next time *don't delete node_modules or package.json or anything*

Comment: thank you, brother, I tried it but still, I'm facing the same issue.